# Existence and Uniqueness of ODEs under weaker Lipschitz continuity condition.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is well known that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally Lipschitz at $x_0$, i.e., there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and $L>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|
\end{align*}
for all $x,y\in U$ then the ODE $\dot{x}=f(x)$ with initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ has a unique solution.
However, assume that we only know that $f$ satisfies the following weaker condition:
there exists a neighborhood $U_2$ of $x_0$ and a constant $L_2>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\|f(x)-f(x_0)\|\leq L_2\|x-x_0\|
\end{align*}
for all $x\in U_2$.
Does existence and uniqueness also hold here? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Not an answer, but some interesting points (especially 5, in terms of looking for counterexamples) https://mathoverflow.net/a/234198/31729

Comment: For a counterexample do you want bifurcation in $x_0$ or near $x_0$? For the second case the IVP $x'=2\sqrt{|x|}$, $x(0)=1$ is a counterexample since $|2\sqrt{|x|}-2| \le 2|x-1|$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I believe the IVP you mentioned has a unique solution right? Namely $x(t)=0$ for $t<-1$ and $x(t)=(t+1)$ for $t\geq-1$. This is because $2\sqrt{|x|}$ is locally Lipschitz at $x=1$, right? I want the bifurcation to be at $x_0$.

Comment: No, this IVP is not uniqely solvable. Two different solutions are for example $x_1(t)=0$ $(t<-1)$, $x_1(t)=(t+1)^2$ $(t \ge -1)$ and $x_2(t)=-(t+1)^2$ $(t<-1)$, $x_2(t)=(1+t)^2$ $(t \ge -1)$. Concerning bifurcation at $x_0$: In case $n=1$ there cannot be a bifurcation at $x_0$. However the case $n>1$ is unclear to me.

Comment: But isn't $2\sqrt{|x|}$ locally Lipschitz around $x=1$? Doesn't that guarantee existence and uniqueness of solutions?

Comment: Yes, locally, but not globally. The solution is unique, as long as $x(t)\not=0$. $x(t)$ hits $0$ at $t=-1$ and then $x'(t)=2\sqrt{|x(t)|}$, $x(-1)=0$ has many solutions to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I think an example that shows that "existence" may fail is the following: Consider
$$
f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, ~ f(x)=1+|x| ~ (x \in \mathbb{Q}), ~ f(x)=1 ~ (x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}),
$$
and the IVP $x'(t)=f(x(t))$, $x(0)=x_0:=0$.
We have
$$
|f(x)-f(x_0)| = |f(x)-1|\le |x|=|x-x_0| \quad (x\in \mathbb{R}).
$$
Assume that $x:[0,\delta] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution of the IVP, for some $\delta > 0$. Since $f\ge 1$ we have $x(t) \ge t$ $(t\in [0, \delta])$. Therefore, for $t \in [\delta/2,\delta]$ we have
$$
x'(t) \ge 1 + \frac{\delta}{2} ~~ \text{if} ~~ x(t) \in \mathbb{Q}, \quad 
x'(t) = 1  ~~ \text{if} ~~ x(t) \notin \mathbb{Q},
$$
and both cases occur. Thus on $[\delta/2,\delta]$ the differentiable function $t \mapsto x(t)$ fails to have the intermediate value property, in contradiction to Darboux's theorem.

Comment: How about if I know that the "weak" Lipschitz property holds for all points of $U_2$? I.e., there exists a neighborhood $U_2$ of $x_0$ such that for all $y\in U_2$ there exists a neighborhood $N_y$ and a constant $L_y>0$ such that $||f(z)-f(y)|| \leq L_y  ||z-y||$ for all $z\in N_y$? Existence holds now because of Peano's theorem, but how about uniqueness?